# SqlExpression Creating Upper SQL Query

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following code:

```
SqlExpression<Postcodes> sqlExpression = db.From<Postcodes>()
                    .Where(x => x.CityId.StartsWith(searchString))
                    .OrderBy(x => x.CityId)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.ZipCode)
                    .Take(take);
```

When I look in debug, I can see that `sqlExpression.BodyExpression` has:

```
FROM "search"."Postcodes"
WHERE upper("CityId") like @0
```

Why does it generate "upper" even though I didn't use `x.CityId.ToUpper()`?

**Update:**
When I use `"nort"` as the input, I can see this in the debug output:

```
2018-11-23 07:37:22,781 [21] DEBUG ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadCommandExtensions [(null)] - SQL: SELECT TOP 100 "ZipCode", "CityId", "StateId" 
FROM "search"."Postcodes"
WHERE upper("CityId") like @0
ORDER BY "CityId", "ZipCode"
PARAMS: @0=NORT%
```

Looks like by default it's using case insensitive matching.

Why is the default case insensitive and how could I force it to do a case sensitive match?

**Update:**
As Gabitu pointed out, it just makes the column name upper case and doesn't affect the query. What is the point in making the column name upper case?

Comment: i'd be suggesting it's trying to be case-insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is doing Upper to your column name, so it wouldn't affect your query at all.

The query will be something like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "search"."Postcodes" 
WHERE CITYID like @0
ORDER BY "CityId"
```

Probably is making it uppercase because your column is case insensitive. Check whether your column is sensitive or insensitive with the following command:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = 'Postcodes' AND 
   CHARACTER_SET_NAME IS NOT NULL AND 
   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'search'
```

Comment: Good point! But what is the point of having the column name upper case?

Comment: Please, have a look on this https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-check-case-sensitivity-sql-server.cfm  Check if your column is case insensitive with this: SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Postcodes' AND CHARACTER_SET_NAME IS NOT NULL AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'search'

Comment: It says "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"